# Modify Child state from parent just once

Tags: reactjs

I have created a `<Form>` Component that makes all the form-fields you give to it controlled by injecting `value` and `onChange` props to the form-fields by iterating through them. This has been working perfectly well for me for most of the forms I have created.

When I needed to have the functionality of the form-field values controlling some aspect of the parent state, I added a `onFormValueChange` prop to the Form that would get called whenever a field value gets updated. Using this I can track a subset of the changes to the Form's state.

However, now my problem is this...how do I override the value of a form-field, conditional on some event that occurs in the parent. **I have not been able to figure out how to override the Form's state just once**. If I give it a prop that sets an override value like `{name: string, value: any}`, then on every update this override value will override the form-field's value which is not good.

These are the solutions I thought of but they seem extremely hacky and I was hoping someone in the SO community can help.

- Set an override prop on the Form Component which times out after around 100ms and hope that the user doesn't try to modify the form in that tiny duration. But I dislike using `setTimeout` for hacks like these.
- Pass a `disableOverride` function along with the `overrideValue` prop. Then in my Form's `shouldComponentUpdate` I can just call `disableOverride()` in the callback of the `setState` I will use to override the value. Something like:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.override) {
      const { name, value } = nextProps.override;
      const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, { [name]: value });
      this.setState(newState, () => {
        nextProps.disableOverride();
      });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

But this also feels unnecessarily complicated, and possibly quite vulnerable to crashing unexpectedly.

**EDIT** Some further clarification: The point of this would be so that for example if I have 'country' and 'city' fields then if 'country' is cleared, then the 'city' should get cleared too. I can track the state of 'country' with `onFormValueChange` but don't have an API to modify the Form state in order to clear the 'city' field.

Comment: You can have an additional flag `updated` on state, if it is `true` then you ignore subsequent changes to state and props.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Your idea would work for the first time that I attempt to override something, but any further attempts to override will no longer work since there would be no way to unset the `update` state. I have edited the question to give further clarification on what the issue is with an example

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly the edit part of your question. Can you add before and after `state` that you expect ?

Comment: That would be before: `{country: "USA", city: "NY"}` And then ,when the user unselects the country thus setting country to "" : `{country: "". city: ""}`. The actual usecase is obviously much more complicated but this should tell you of the basic idea. The problem is not in setting the state but in setting it **once** on a Child component on triggering of an event in the Parent component.

Comment: Can't you update the flag, when the users selects/inputs country ?

Comment: @UtsavPatel You're saying set it as false initially...set it to true when the override is set...and then set it back to false on the change handler of the form-field?

Comment: Yes, only when the user removes country, if it modifies it then leave it as is.

Comment: @UtsavPatel I did find a solution in case you are curious. it was very simple and should probably have occurred to me sooner. Posted it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution. It was absurdly simple, I dont know why it took me so long.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (!isEqual(prevProps.override, this.props.override)) {
      const { name, value } = nextProps.override;
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    }
  }
```

`isEqual` is an object comparison function taken from lodash